# sending req.body from React to Express then post to api

Tags: reactjs, api, express, post, axios

I am attempting to send a forms body from React to Express and then post it to an API. Everything seems to work getting the body from React to Express but Im unsure how to then post this to the API. GET requests work fine from the API its just getting the data to POST back to the API Im having issues with. Im also using AXIOS. Any advice or links to tutorials appreciated.

SiteAdd.js - gets form data from state and fetches route from Express server.

```
       handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //deconstruct
    const { id, siteRef, addrType, addr1, addr2, city, county, postCode, country } = this.state;
    const site = {
      id,
      siteRef,
      addrType,
      addr1,
      addr2,
      city,
      county,
      postCode,
      country
    };

   fetch('/api/siteAdd', site)
      .then(() => console.log('Site Created'))
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

server.js - the Express server

```
       var express = require('express')
    var http = require('http')
    //var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require('cors')
    const path = require('path')
    var app = express()
    var axios = require('axios')

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors())

    //get
    //working
    app.get('/api/site', (req, res, next) => {
        axios.get('https://****/api/site/')
        .then(response => res.json(response.data))
            .catch(err => next(err));
    })

let sites = [];
app.post('/api/siteAdd', function (req, res) {
    const newSite = {
        id: req.body.id,
        siteRef: req.body.siteRef,
        addrType: req.body.addrType,
        addr1: req.body.addr1,
        addr2: req.body.addr2,
        city: req.body.city,
        county: req.body.county,
        postCode: req.body.postCode,
        country: req.body.country,
    };

    sites.push(newSite);
    console.log(sites);
});
```

Comment: You can get more detail about what goes wrong with your server code by starting your server with the options: `i--inspect-brk ` more info [here](https://flaviocopes.com/node-debug-devtools/). I'd advice you set a breakpoint before the axios.post and try to run code from the console, maybe something is wrong with req.body

Comment: I have updated my app.post code which now works and I get the req.body queries in console log which is good. How do I now post this to the api? Same as the GET request ive included which works but POST instead?

Comment: It looks like your client does not make a correct post request. [Here[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) is a post request example for fetch.

Comment: Also' instead of using axios on the server and fetch on the client why not use fetch on both server and client. You can use [this fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch) for the server.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Im a bit confused as to were the post request to the api needs to be made.  I thought this was done from the server. sites.push(newSite) seems to do nothing as when I check the api in postman its not there.

Comment: axios.get('https://****/api/site/') works fine though and i can map over the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the error logs on the backend that is returning a status code of `500`. Something wrong is happening on the server where you are trying to post the data.

Comment: my updated code now works because console.log shows all the req.body data from client. sites.push(newSite) doesnt seem to do anything though. How would i post this to the api?